# socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed when using IP from file, but not when IP is hardcoded

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10

I am trying to create a simple script (I'm using Python 3.10.6) to perform IP-to-Hostname resolution from a file that contains a list of IP addresses.

Here is my code:

```
with open('ciscoIP.txt') as ipAdd:
for ipAddress in ipAdd:
    print(ipAddress)
    try:
        print(socket.gethostbyaddr(ipAddress))
    except socket.herror as err:
            print ("cannot resolve hostname: ", ipAddress, err)
```

When I run this, I receive the error:

```
File "ipLookup.py", line 29, in <module>
  print(socket.gethostbyaddr(ipAddress))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

However, if I hardcode an IP:

```
print(socket.gethostbyaddr('8.8.8.8'))
```

The command executes without error.

The issue only seems to be when reading the IP from the file and using that as the variable.

I also tried:

```
print(socket.gethostbyaddr(str(ipAddress)))
```

But I still receive the same error.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check if the line has any leading or trailing white spaces?. May be calling `ipAddress.strip()` will be a good option.

Comment: You're brilliant.  I don't see any white space in the text file, but this fixed it.  Thank you!!!